# Error: Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'String' is not valid

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on a project where I get data from a database.

Now I get this error message:

> Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'String' is not valid

I know what the error means, I just need a way to fix it.

I have the following code:

```
 Private Function ParseSeamansNames(ByVal seaman As ItemsDataSet.SeamenRow) As String
        If (seaman Is Nothing) Then Return String.Empty

        Dim name As String
        Dim firstNames() As String = Split(seaman.FirstName.Replace("-", " "))
        Dim index1 As Integer = CInt(seaman.GivenNameNumber.Substring(0, 1))
        Dim index2 As Integer = CInt(seaman.GivenNameNumber.Substring(1, 1))
        If (index1 > firstNames.Length - 1) Then
            index1 = 0
        End If
        If (index2 > firstNames.Length - 1) Then
            index2 = 0
        End If
        If (index1 = 0 And index2 = 0) Then
            name = seaman.FirstName
        ElseIf (index1 > 0 And index2 = 0) Then
            name = firstNames(index1 - 1)
        ElseIf (index1 = 0 And index2 > 0) Then
            name = firstNames(index2 - 1)
        Else
            name = firstNames(index1 - 1) & "-" & firstNames(index2 - 1)
        End If
        name = name & " " & seaman.LastName

        Return name
    End Function
```

I tried to change it to `If (seaman Is Nothing) Then Return DBNull` but I get error:

> dbnull is a type and cannot be used as an expression

I don't really know how to fix it. Can anyone help me?

**UPDATE:**

I get this error:

> [InvalidCastException: Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'String'
>   is not valid.]
>   Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToString(Object
>   Value) +715847
>   BUMSSeamenWebb.ItemsService.SeamenRow.get_FirstName() in C:\BUMS
>   LOKAL\Dev\Projects\BUMSSeamenWebb\Web
>   References\ItemsService\Reference.vb:51036

That line is this code:

```
 <Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute(),  _
             Global.System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Data.Design.TypedDataSetGenerator", "4.0.0.0")>  _
            Public Property FirstName() As String
                Get
                    Try 
                        Return CType(Me(Me.tableSeamen.FirstNameColumn),String)
                    Catch e As Global.System.InvalidCastException
                        Throw New Global.System.Data.StrongTypingException("The value for column 'FirstName' in table 'Seamen' is DBNull.", e)
                    End Try
                End Get
                Set
                    Me(Me.tableSeamen.FirstNameColumn) = value
                End Set
            End Property
```

In particular:

```
 Return CType(Me(Me.tableSeamen.FirstNameColumn),String)
```

I can't see the problem here

**UPDATE 2:**

This is another function that checks other columns

```
 Private Sub SetSeamanData(ByRef itemRow As ItemsDataSet.ItemsRow, ByVal seaman As ItemsDataSet.SeamenRow)
        itemRow.PersonalIdentityNumber = seaman.PersonalIdentityNumber
        itemRow.Name = ParseSeamansNames(seaman)
        itemRow.CitizenShipCode = seaman.CitizenshipCode
        If Not seaman.IsEmailNull() Then
            itemRow.EmailAddress = seaman.Email
        Else
            itemRow.EmailAddress = Nothing
        End If
        If Not seaman.IsTelephoneNull() Then
            itemRow.TelephoneNumber = seaman.Telephone
        Else
            itemRow.TelephoneNumber = Nothing
        End If
        If Not seaman.IsMobiletelephoneNull() Then
            itemRow.MobilephoneNumber = seaman.Mobiletelephone
        Else
            itemRow.MobilephoneNumber = Nothing
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: @sstan Thanks, I updated my question. I appreciate it if you could check it again.

Comment: `If Not IsDBNull` then perform your checks...Do keep in mind that `DBNull` is NOT in fact the same as `Nothing`

Comment: Also as a side note, it might be good to check to make sure the values you're casting to INT are in fact numbers before you try and cast them...

Comment: `DataRow` type have extension method `.Field(Of T)`, which can be used for `String` without `null` checking. Return `Nothing` if value is `DBNull`

Answer (score 1):

These generated `DataRow` classes are coded in such a way that if you try to read a property (column value) that has a database null value, it will throw an exception.

You are expected to check for null *before* attempting to read from it.

As you can tell from the message, in this case it's complaining that you are trying to read the value of `FirstName`, but it's null (`DbNull`).

Usually, when a column can be null, these `DataRow` classes also include a convenience function to check for null on that specific column.  So in this case, `ItemsDataSet.SeamenRow` should also have a `IsFirstNameNull` function.  If so, call that first, and handle that specific case. If `IsFirstNameNull` returns `false`, then you can safely read from the `FirstName` property.

If you have other columns that can be null in your database, you will need to follow a similar pattern.

Comment: I do have a `IsFirstNameNull` function that checks for null, I just never used it I guess. I have another function that checks for null, please check my **Update 2**. Is the `IsFirstNameNull` supposed to work in similar way? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, exactly. That's the pattern.